# How to show popup on top of all other apps in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building a test app for practicing ionic where I need to add a feature like Whatsapp popup.

I know I can do it with `system_alert_window`.

But I'm using ionic 3 with Cordova. How can I achieve it?

Comment: did you manage to find something about this, I also have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a alert controller in ionic3

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

presentAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Low battery',
    subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });
  alert.present();
}

presentConfirm() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm purchase',
    message: 'Do you want to buy this book?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Buy',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Buy clicked');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

You can read more about this here :
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/

Comment: note the title -  "on top of all other apps" hence down vote.